# Realm JS opening all Schemas in app. Bad practice?

Tags: database, typescript, react-native, sqlite, realm

I would like to create a utility class for Realm for my application, keeping most of the complexity with Realm in this class. To make life easier I proposed when opening a Realm instance I open all schemas within the app. As shown below:

```
export default class RealmAccess {
    private realm!: Realm;
    private allSchemas = [OneSchema, TwoSchema, ThreeSchema ... ];

    private async open(schemaList: ObjectSchema[] = this.allSchemas): Promise<void> {
        this.realm = await open({ schema: schemaList });
    }
}
```

Would this be considered bad practice?

Would this affect app performance at all when fetching/saving data? As an example we can assume each schema has a minimum of 500 rows.

I can't seem to find anything in the docs about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supplying the full schema every time you open a Realm is the normal way to do things. There is no performance benefit to only listing the subset of object types you're going to use.